# Can I download anti-virus update signatures separately?

Tags: ms-security-essentials

I recently installed [Microsoft's Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/mse) on a family members PC, having previously downloaded the installer over broadband, as their PC is limited to 46K dial-up.

Once installed, we set MSE away updating and after 4 hours (and 62MB!) it said it was still only half complete!

Is it possible to download the latest updates for MSE separately, and then update it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**

On the [MSE update troubleshooting page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/troubleshooting-update-issues), step 6 provides the following two links:

- If you're running a 32-bit Windows operating system, download the
  latest updates manually at
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=87342.
- If you're running a 64-bit Windows operating system, download the
  latest updates manually at
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=87341.

Comment: .. size of the 32-bit update?  ~63MB - if I'd only left it running another 5 minutes..  d'oh!